# Send mail each time with different ip

Tags: c#, email, ip

i have a win server 2003 with 3 ips , i am making a program that sends a bulk mails , but i`d like to switch between the 3 ips while sending emails , say for example , first mail sent using first ip and second mail using second ip and third mail using third ip , i know how to send mails using C# , but is there any class that chooses switch ip or something , i am actually not expecting codes , i want any idea so i can start digging .

Comment: How about setting up three mail servers (e.g. [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/)), one working on each IP address. [According to the author, this is possible](http://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=13600). Your C# code could then communication with the tree.

Comment: Also, there is [a similar question on SF](http://serverfault.com/questions/134568/how-to-send-mail-with-hmailserver-from-different-ips-for-different-domains) which may be helpful to you.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Sounds like spam; not interested in promoting this. Voting to close as too-localized.

Comment: It looks like you were trying to make a spam generator. Is this really something the world was waiting for?

Comment: nope it it not a spamming , i just try not to send from 1 server as it will cause server monopolization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 IPs are not enough. Do you have 3 Mailservers using the 3 ips ? If yes it is possible.

I would use `Random`...

```
Random r = new Random();
int mailServer = r.Next(1, 3);
SmtpClient client;

if (mailServer == 1) client = new SmtpClient("mail1.yourdomain.com");
else if (mailServer == 2) client = new SmtpClient("mail2.yourdomain.com");
else client = new SmtpClient("mail3.yourdomain.com");

client.Send(...);
```

Comment: That`s a good example , thank you very much , i though of switching ips but this looks amazing too .

Answer (score 1):

`SmtpClient` constructor as you know accepts address of your server, so you can use it that way

```
class Program
{
    static string[] addresses = new string[] 
        { "192.168.0.1", "215.100.100.100", "110.100.100.100" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SmtpClient server1 = GetClient(0);
        // stuff to send mail with 1st server
        SmtpClient server2 = GetClient(1);
        // stuff to send mail with 2nd server
        // etc.

    }

    private static SmtpClient GetClient(int id)
    {
        if (addresses[id] != null)
            return new SmtpClient(addresses[id]);
        throw new ArgumentException("No such server");
    }
}
```